# Hive : Concat a map

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I have a small trouble into Hive, when I try to concatenate map

Assume that I've something like that :

```
var 1 | var 2

x | map(key1:value1)

x | map(key2:value2)

x | map(key3:value3)

y | map(key4:value4)
```

What I'am trying to get, It's something like that

```
var 1 | var 2

x | map(key1:value1 ; key2:value2; key3:value3)

y | map(key4,value4)
```

Something like a map concatenation.

How can I proceed whith Hive ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query...

select var1,collect_set(CONCAT_WS(',',map_keys(var2),map_values(var2))) as var2 from example group by var1;

This will get you output like this...

### var1 | var2

x    |      ["key1,value1","key2,value2","key3,value3"]

y    |     ["key4,value4"]

Comment: A small trouble with this method, because my map look like :{place:10} and I got this error : Argument 3 of function CONCAT_WS must be "string or array<string>", but "array<bigint>" was found.

Comment: Unfortunately, ListType cannot be cast to PrimitiveType (like String).  The only solution I can think of is defining map as String,String.

Comment: Yes. It is the best solution that I found too, Thanks ! Just in case, If we have another basic type that string, we should use `select var1,collect_set(CONCAT_WS(',',map_keys(var2),cast(map_values(var2) as String))) as var2 from example group by var1;`