# Hive concat two map object

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables as follow in hive:

**Table 1**

```
key1  | value1

int   | map(int,array(int))
```

**Table 2**

```
key2  |  value2

int   | map(int,array(int))
```

and now I join the table on key and I want to concat two maps that have the same key. In other words the final should looklike .

**Table**

```
key  |  value

int  | map(int,array(int))
```

I tried to use function collect_set when I am joining as follows:

```
collect_set(value1,value2)
```

but it through exception that only one input is required. Any thoughts or comments?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723159/hive-concat-a-map

Comment: Please add a full example with data (and not metadata)

Answer (score 2):

`COLLECT_SET()` is an aggregate function so it wouldn't really be useful (or valid) if you are trying to combine things.  One thing you could try is using `COMBINE()`.  It can be found in this library of UDFs [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/tree/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect).  Suppose you had some data like:

**table0**:

```
idx     map_kv
0       {2:[1,2,3,4], 3:[5,6,7,8,9]}
```

**table1**:

```
idx     map_kv
0       {2:[5,6,7,8,9], 3:[1,2,3,4]}
```

Then you could do

**Query**:

```
ADD JAR /path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION COLLECT AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION COMBINE AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUDF';

SELECT idx
  , COLLECT(map_key, arr) AS final_map
FROM (
  SELECT a.idx
    , a.map_key
    , COMBINE(map_val_0, map_val_1) AS arr
  FROM (
    SELECT idx
      , map_key
      , map_val_0
    FROM database.table0
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(map_kv) exptbl0 AS map_key, map_val_0 ) a
  JOIN (
    SELECT idx
      , map_key
      , map_val_1
    FROM database.table1
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(map_kv) exptbl1 AS map_key, map_val_1 ) b
  ON a.idx=b.idx AND a.map_key=b.map_key ) c
GROUP BY idx;
```

This will produce:

**Output**:

```
idx     final_map
0       {2:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3:[5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4]}
```